# Pandas dot product ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, dot-product

I am trying to calculate the dot product of a data frame and a series, but I am getting `ValueError: matrices are not aligned`  and I do not really understand why. I get

```
if (len(common) > len(self.columns) or len(common) > len(other.index)):
    raise ValueError('matrices are not aligned')
```

with the error message, which I totally understand. But when I check my series, it has 25 values:

```
    weights
    Out[193]: 
    0     0.000002
    1     0.000577
    2     0.002480
    3     0.004720
    4     0.003640
    5     0.001480
    6     0.000054
    7     0.000022
    8     0.009060
    9     0.000511
    10    0.034900
    11    0.140000
    12    0.065600
    13    0.325000
    14    0.072900
    15    0.031100
    16    0.209000
    17    0.003280
    18    0.001390
    19    0.002100
    20    0.000847
    21    0.009560
    22    0.006320
    23    0.014000
    24    0.061900
    Name: 3, dtype: float64
```

And when I check my data frame, it also has 25 columns:

```
    In [195]: data
    Out[195]: 
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Int64Index: 131 entries, 0 to 130
    Data columns (total 25 columns):
```

(etc)

So I don't understand why I get the error message. What am I missing here?

Some additional information:
I am using `weightedave=data.dot(weights)`
And I just figured out in the dot code that it does `common = data.columns.union(weights.index)` to get the `common` referred to in the error message. So I tested that, but in my case that becomes

```
    In[220]: common
    Out[220]: Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, u'100_AVET', u'101_AVET', u'102_AVET', u'13_AVET', u'14_AVET', u'15_AVET', u'18_AVET', u'19_AVET', u'20_AVET', u'22_AVET', u'36_AVET', u'62_AVET', u'74_AVET', u'78_AVET', u'79_AVET', u'80_AVET', u'83_AVET', u'85_AVET', u'86_AVET', u'88_AVET', u'94_AVET', u'95_AVET', u'96_AVET', u'97_AVET', u'99_AVET'], dtype=object)
```

Which indeed is longer (50) than my number of columns/indices (25). Should I rename either my series or the columns in my data frame?

Comment: What code are you using to calculate the dot product, that raises the ValueError? You probably need to transpose `data` (`data.T`) so that the dot product makes sense. Also keep in mind that pandas aligns the labels those need to match.

Comment: Try `data.T.dot(weights)`